# Set timeout error when using routes with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am using VueJS and I want to push data to the server and afterwards change the route.

I've tried this:

```
saveSupportArea: function () {
  this.toast("success");
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function(that){
    that.$router.push('/areas/');
  }, 3000);
});
```

But I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$router' of undefined

Can anybody help?

Comment: don't pass `that` as the parameter of the anonymous function passed to `setTimeout`

Comment: Omg, it works!
Can you explain why was wrong? And maaanyy thanks!!! :) :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass `that` as the parameter of the anonymous function passed to `setTimeout`.

Doing so effectively resets `that` within the scope of the anonymous function because you are defining it again as a parameter for the function. That function is never given a parameter, so it is `undefined`, meaning that `that` is `undefined` when it tries to access the `$router` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeforeRouteLeave function then describe setTimeout inside of that function.